# What is the most common way to ingest JSON file changes from Azure BLOB storage into Logstash?

Tags: logstash, azure-blob-storage, elastic-stack, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I have a need to integrate Logstash data ingestion to include JSON files which are stored in an Azure BLOB storage container. These JSON files are being constantly appended to and Logstash is expected to "tail" these files and to process every newly added record to Elasticsearch. With such files being local we do have a working Logstash input implementation:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/logs/json/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
    # remove this for not always starting from the beginning of the file
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => "json"
    type => "json"
    mode => "tail"
  }
}
```

With the files being stored in an Azure BLOB storage container this input will obviously not work. In the past there were a couple of open-source Logstash input plugins such as

```
input { 
    azure_blob_storage {
```

but these no longer supported / generally available.

What is the most common / supportable way to get the continuously added records from Azure BLOB storage and into the Logstash?

Answer (score 0):

You can test the **Azure Event Hubs plugin**

This is the official [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-azure_event_hubs.html) you can find sections explaining the Blob Storage connection.

There is also a possibility to use filebeat and use this plugin **filebeat-input-azure-blob-storage**

check this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-azure-blob-storage.html)